# Lightning Pages vs VF Pages

Tags: visualforce, lightning-apps, lightning

We have a requirement to build a lengthy wizard (spanning ~6-8 visualforce pages) and would like to know whether the advanced functionalities that we have used in Visualforce Development will be available (or atleast a comparable alternatives) in Lightning Component Framework also.

a) Wizard with the facility to query/insert/delete data from multiple custom objects

b) Able to support jQuery plugins

c) Custom lookups

d) Toggling visibility between panels

e) Showing lists of records and the ability to choose them (we used to implement them in VF via wrapper classes) for edit/delete.

These features mentioned above are what we have used to utilize in VF...do we have comparable features in Lightning Pages also ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning is available in GA from this release .You can ofcourse approach via lightning .Some of the things you need to be extra careful are here

1)No router support in lightning yet and hence its extremely difficult designing navigation at this point .You will end up writing lot of code just to achieve navigations

2)Custom lookups you can get from [developerforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html) blogs

3)Toggling visibility is not so difficult

4)Supporting jquery in lightning is possible but you need to be careful when using this and would recommend to use less as possible

5)Spinning a list is not so difficult with excellent repeater .

6)Currently to make experience seamless lightning expereince also needs to be turned on for all your users .

Since there will be additional learning and experimenting take decision based on budget and time lines .

Building in lightning is like giving awesome quality work with lot of resusable at cost of little more time .

Comment: Mohith, what are your thoughts about the potential problem that not all users will have Lightning Experience turned on?

Comment: @KeithC Ah i completely forgot about that .This needs to be added .Not all users will have lightning turned on for desktop .